# How to make a select correctly in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following problem: There is a gigantic query that concatenates a set of user-selectable conditions (select boxes, text fields, etc.). 
By default, if nothing is selected anyway (not have conditions), sorting according to various parameters (Order by). The problem is that if there is a conditions, we have to add the word "WHERE", and only once, but should not add it if there are no conditions, since it is impossible to write after WHERE ORDER BY. How to solve this problem?

```php
$payment_select = "select payment_id,
        payment_agreement,
                payment_dateagreement,
                payment_action,
                payment_close,
                payment_charge,
                payment_pay,
                study_id,
                card_id,
                name_nominative,
                surname_nominative,
                patr_nominative,
                studgroups_number,
                dep_name,
                study_kurs`

        from
                study
        inner join card on card_id = study_card_id
        inner join name on name_id = card_name_id
        inner join surname on surname_id = card_surname_id
        inner join dep on dep_id = study_dep_id
        inner join studgroups on study_studgroups_id = studgroups_id
        left join payment on study_id = payment_study_id
        left join patr on patr_id = card_patr_id
        ";

        if (isset($name_filter) && ($name_filter)) {
            $payment_select. = " and name_nominative like '%".$name_filter. "%' ";
        }
        if (isset($surname_filter) && ($surname_filter)) {
            $payment_select. = " and surname_nominative like '%".$surname_filter. "%' ";
        }
        if (isset($patr_filter) && ($patr_filter)) {
            $payment_select. = " and patr_nominative like '%".$patr. "%' ";
        }
        if (isset($group_filter) && ($group_filter)) {
            $payment_select. = " and studgroups_number like '%".$group_filter. "%' ";
        }
        if (isset($agreement_filter) && ($agreement_filter)) {
            $payment_select. = " and payment_agreement like '%".$agreement_filter. "%' ";
        }
        if (isset($debt_filter) && ($debt_filter == 1)) {
            $payment_select. = " and (payment_charge - payment_pay) > 0 ";
        }
        if (isset($debt_filter) && ($debt_filter == 2)) {
            $payment_select. = " and (payment_charge - payment_pay) <= 0 ";
        }
        if (isset($card_filter) && $card_filter) {
            $payment_select. = " and card_id = '$card_filter' ";
        }
        if (isset($study_filter) && $study_filter) {
            $payment_select. = " and study_id = '$study_filter' ";
        }
        if (isset($recordbook_filter) and $recordbook_filter){
            $payment_select. = " and study_recordbook like '$recordbook_filter%' ";
        }
        if (isset($action_filter) && ($action_filter == 1)) {
            $payment_select. = " and payment_action = 1 ";
        }
        if (isset($action_filter) && ($action_filter == 2)) {
            $payment_select. = " and payment_action = 0 ";
        }
        if (isset($close_filter) && ($close_filter == 1)) {
            $payment_select. = " and payment_close = 0 ";
        }
        if (isset($close_filter) && ($close_filter == 2)) {
            $payment_select. = " and payment_close = 1 ";
        }

        if (isset($dep_filter) && ($dep_filter)) {
            $dep = select_dep_array();
            $payment_select. = " and dep_acronym like '".$dep[$dep_filter]. "' ";
        }
        if (isset($kurs_filter) && ($kurs_filter > 1)) {
            $payment_select. = " and study_kurs = ". ($kurs_filter - 1). " ";
        }
        if (isset($educform_filter) && ($educform_filter >= 1)) {
            $payment_select. = " and study_formeduc_id = ".$educform_filter. " ";
        }
        if (isset($progr_filter) && ($progr_filter >= 1)) {
            $payment_select. = " and study_program_id = ".$progr_filter. " ";
        }
        if (preg_match("/^\d(\d)?\.\d(\d)?\.\d\d\d\d$/", $date_from_filter)) {
            $date_from_mysql = date_user_to_mysql($date_from_filter);
        } else {
            if ($date_from_filter)
                $error_msg = "Дата введена неправильно.";
        }
        if (preg_match("/^\d(\d)?\.\d(\d)?\.\d\d\d\d$/", $date_to_filter)) {
            $date_to_mysql = date_user_to_mysql($date_to_filter);
        } else {
            if ($date_to_filter)
                $error_msg = "Дата введена неправильно.";
        }
        if ((isset($date_from_mysql) && ($date_from_mysql)) && !(isset($date_to_mysql) && ($date_to_mysql))) {
            $payment_select. = "and payment_date_agreement >= '".$date_from_mysql. "' ";
        }
        if (!(isset($date_from_mysql) && ($date_from_mysql)) && (isset($date_to_mysql) && ($date_to_mysql))) {
            $payment_select. = "and payment_dateagreement <= '".$date_to_mysql. "' ";
        }

        if ((isset($date_from_mysql) && ($date_from_mysql)) && (isset($date_to_mysql) && ($date_to_mysql))) {
            $payment_select. = "and payment_dateagreement >= '".$date_from_mysql.
            "' and payment_dateagreement <= '".$date_to_mysql. "' ";
        }

        if (isset($order) && ($order)) {
            if ($order == 3) {
                if ($desc) {
                    $payment_select. = " order by surname_nominative desc, name_nominative desc, patr_nominative desc";
                } else {
                    $payment_select. = " order by ".$order_array[$order];
                }

            } else {
                $payment_select. = " order by ".$order_array[$order];
                if ($desc) {
                    $payment_select. = " desc ";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't `WHERE 1 = 1 ` a standard php trick?

Comment: You could of course also just not concatenate all these conditions to `$payment_select` directly, but use a helper variable to assemble those; and then you simply check whether that helper variable contains anything at the very end - if so, `WHERE` and the content of that variable get appended to the query, or simply - nothing.

Comment: Off topic (slightly) but useful. I use "Where (1=1) and", "Where (2=2) and"... in lots of queries to help me find them in code easily. When you get an error, you can go search for the (4=4) bit.

Comment: You should try some DB abstraction library for such tasks. You have a much more serious problem regarding SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly extend your SQL, you can first collect all your "where clauses" in an array and then check if it is not empty and then implode it. Like this:

```
//your select
$payment_select = "SELECT ....";

//helper var
$where_clauses = [];

//from your example
if (isset($name_filter) && ($name_filter)) {
    $where_clauses[] = "name_nominative like '%".$name_filter. "%'";
}

//from your example
if (isset($surname_filter) && ($surname_filter)) {
    $where_clauses[] = "surname_nominative like '%".$surname_filter. "%'";
}

//now append the clauses if there any
if (! empty($where_clauses)) {
    $payment_select .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where_clauses)
}
```